# View removing history with latest version

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, window-functions, sql-view

I have this table:

TABLE S_TEXT:

```
PS_TEXT     S_TEXT   VS_TEXT        D_TEXT  
1           1        1              Hey                 
2           1        1              Hello
3           1        2              Oh
4           2        1              Hallo
5           2        1              Hallo
6           2        2              Hi
```

Then I have this view to remove all history doublets:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `VHS_TEXT`
AS SELECT 
`S_TEXT`.`PS_TEXT`, 
`S_TEXT`.`S_TEXT`, 
`S_TEXT`.`VS_TEXT`, 
`S_TEXT`.`D_TEXT`
FROM 
`S_TEXT` LEFT JOIN 
`S_TEXT` AS `t2`
ON (
`S_TEXT`.`S_TEXT` = `t2`.`S_TEXT` AND `S_TEXT`.`PS_TEXT` < `t2`.`PS_TEXT`
)
WHERE
`t2`.`PS_TEXT` IS NULL;
```

VIEW VHS_TEXT:

```
PS_TEXT     S_TEXT  VS_TEXT     D_TEXT  
3           1       2           Oh
6           2       2           Hi
```

Then I have this view to show versions without doublets:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `VVS_TEXT`
AS SELECT 
`S_TEXT`.`PS_TEXT`, 
`S_TEXT`.`S_TEXT`, 
`S_TEXT`.`VS_TEXT`, 
`S_TEXT`.`D_TEXT`
FROM 
`S_TEXT` LEFT JOIN 
`S_TEXT` AS `t2`
ON (
`S_TEXT`.`S_TEXT` = `t2`.`S_TEXT`
AND `S_TEXT`.`VS_TEXT` = `t2`.`VS_TEXT`
AND `S_TEXT`.`PS_TEXT` < `t2`.`PS_TEXT`
)
WHERE
`t2`.`PS_TEXT` IS NULL;
```

VIEW VVS_TEXT:

```
PS_TEXT     S_TEXT   VS_TEXT        D_TEXT  
2           1        1              Hello
3           1        2              Oh
5           2        1              Hallo
6           2        2              Hi
```

Now I insert one new row instance 2 version 1:

```
PS_TEXT     S_TEXT   VS_TEXT        D_TEXT  
1           1        1              Hey                 
2           1        1              Hello
3           1        2              Oh
4           2        1              Hallo
5           2        1              Hallo
6           2        2              Hi
7           2        1              Hi too
```

Now I get this in VHS_TEXT:

```
PS_TEXT     S_TEXT  VS_TEXT     D_TEXT  
3           1       2           Oh
7           2       1           Hi too
```

But I want this:

```
 PS_TEXT    S_TEXT  VS_TEXT     D_TEXT  
 3          1       2           Oh
 6          2       2           Hi
```

The desired query/view can be defined like this:

- one row for each distinct S_TEXT
- show latest version VS_TEXT of S_TEXT with latest revision PS_TEXT

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` for this:

```
create view vhs_text as
select ps_text, s_text, vs_text, d_text 
from (
    select 
        s.*,
        row_number() over(partition by s_text order by vs_text desc) rn
    from s_text s
) x
where rn = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ibtSq4zGsE1tzW6U61PJyT/2)**:

```
| ps_text | s_text | vs_text | d_text |
| ------- | ------ | ------- | ------ |
| 3       | 1      | 2       | Oh     |
| 6       | 2      | 2       | Hi     |
```

---

On earlier versions, you can use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
create view vhs_text as
select *
from s_text s
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from s_text s1
    where s1.s_text = s.s_text and s1.vs_text > s.vs_text
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ibtSq4zGsE1tzW6U61PJyT/3)** (same result)

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I do not have MySQL 8. MySQL 8 is surely a major upgrade bringing a lot of nice Oracle features into the MySQL world :-)

Comment: @HenrikHansen: I updated my answer with a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: It actually doesn't work on a larger scale. It only works on the given data because only one entry exists for the latest version.

Comment: @HenrikHansen: this did not show in your sample data... How do you want to handle that use case?

Comment: true the sample data was not comprehensive enough. However, the use case is explained as getting the latest version in latest revision, instead of getting latest revision, which might not be the latest version.